# Where does Geoserver get the Lat/Lon Bounding Box Values from?

Tags: geoserver, extents, image-mosaic

I have an image mosaic layer using a postgis database to index the granules.

In the following screenshot where does geoserver get the values for the Lat/Lon Bounding Box from?:

[image]

If I run the following query on the coorisponding postgis table

```
SELECT ST_Extent(the_geom) FROM agdd_anomaly_50f;
```

I get the result:

```
BOX(-125.020833333333 24.0625,-66.479166666662 49.937500000002)
```

Which is consistent with the native bounding box, but not the Lat/Long Bounding box. I add new rows to the table agdd_anomaly_50f nightly, but I always set "the_geom" to be identical to all the previously added rows.

I realize if I hit "Compute from Native Bounds" that the bbox will be corrected, but somehow every so often the values change back to what's shown in the screen shot and I don't know where they are coming from. I've grepped for those numbers in all the config files I know of for the layer but nothing comes up.

Comment: Since you hit the "Compute from Native Bounds"  did you press "save"?

Comment: @pavlos yes I hit save afterward and the change sticks for sometime. I don't know what causes it to revert to the screen shot numbers. That's why I'm curious as to where those numbers are retrieved from / stored or how they are computed.